# Unwanted redirection

Tags: 7, redirection, advertising

My website's client (eole.avh.asso.fr) has been hacked following the recent hack of drupal core.

We have updated the drupal core on our website, but when we try to reach the url "eole.avh.asso.fr/admin/index", we're redirected to a spam website with an iframe, the url remaining the same.

So far, we deleted all the unwanted files and checked all the files (modules, system, themes, etc.) and the database to see if a redirection is hidden, but without success.

Has anyone meet this problem recently ?

Comment: Did you look at all .htaccess files?

Comment: Yeah man go through Every .htaccess file on your server and replace with default ones ... as thats usully how they get that ...

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I already checked all the .htaccess files

Comment: You could try to set up an exact clone of your live site on a local machine with internet connection turned off, and try to load the site and try to pinpoint at which point the redirect happens, hopefully it helps.